Why does SSIS read different data format when the Excel file is open vs closed?
I'm using SSIS to read data from Excel file.
In the connection manager connection string I've set IMEX=1 to allow reading intermixed data types, and unchecked First row is header to ensure that the first line is text therefore it guarantees reading of intermixed data types.
The query is
SELECT * FROM [SHEET1$]

This data is then written into a SQL Server table with columns defined as nvarchar datatype.
What I'm observing is that - when the Excel file is open vs closed, different results get displayed in the Excel data source task's Preview, and same is observed in the data that gets written into the database table.
Taking the example of a number column (example: 2,000) and a percentage column (example: 90%).
If the Excel file is kept open, and I run the package, then the preview shows 2000 and 0.9. The same gets written into the database table as well.
Whereas if I close the file, and run the package, then the preview shows 2,000 and 90%. The same gets written into the database table.
Why is it showing different values of data if the file is open vs closed when running the package? What is the correct approach to consistently read data correctly from Excel files having intermixed values?

Aside... frankly I'm surprised you can read the file at all when it's open in Excel. Historically the Office apps have taken FileAccess.ReadWrite + FileShare.None locks on files that prevent other processes that even opening them for reading.

"What is the correct approach to consistently read data correctly from Excel files having intermixed values?" Honestly, don't use Excel files. ACE likes to make it's own decisions, and it's difficult to force it to make them differently. Use something else, such as a CSV, JSON or XML; as the data is text then you are in control not some driver that bases its decisions of infering.

@AlwaysLearning - maybe IMEX=1 has different behaviour.
